# How can tensorflow_model_server bind its HTTP/REST on 0.0.0.0 (default localhost)?

Tags: tensorflow, tensorflow-serving

I found that docker image TensorFlow/serving actually use the executable `tensorflow_model_server` to start a server. So I attach into a docker container to 
start the server manually.

My command:

```
tensorflow_model_server --model_base_path=/root/serving/my_image_classifier/ --rest_api_port=8501 --model_name=ImageClassifier
```

This command start the server, with logs:

```
2018-11-27 03:56:43.302391: I tensorflow_serving/core/loader_harness.cc:86] Successfully loaded servable version {name: ImageClassifier version: 2}

2018-11-27 03:56:43.304439: I tensorflow_serving/model_servers/server.cc:286] Running gRPC ModelServer at 0.0.0.0:8500 ...

[warn] getaddrinfo: address family for nodename not supported

2018-11-27 03:56:43.306009: I tensorflow_serving/model_servers/server.cc:302] Exporting HTTP/REST API at:localhost:8501
```

As it says，its HTTP/REST API exported as localhost. That's not right, cause if a sever bind on localhost in docker, it cannot be attach from outside.

I read --help arefully, but didn't find anything usefully.

**So, how can I let it bind on 0.0.0.0?**

TensorFlow ModelServer version:

```
TensorFlow ModelServer: 1.12.0-rc0+dev.sha.87470f0
TensorFlow Library: 1.12.0
```

Comment: I've looked around in the code, and I don't think it's easily configurable. You could fork TensorFlow serving, and modify the code (although it does not seem like an easy task). You could also open an [issue on the tensorflow serving Github](https://github.com/tensorflow/serving/issues)

Comment: Cant you expose the port in the Docker image?

Answer (score 1):

In fact, even the logs show that the HTTP/REST API bind on "localhost", it actucally **can be attached** outside of the docker container.

Why I could not attach that is another strange problem (whitch automatic disapeared after the machine rebooted).

However, I still think the tensorflow_model_server uses "localhost" in log is not right, especially when it tells RPC bind on "0.0.0.0".

I should open an issue.

Comment: DId u find a solution for this ? I am seeing the same issue and trying to understand the issue.